# what is the recommended pattern for a root saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a rootSage and i would like to know which implementation is right and what are the benefits over the other.

A) Implementation 1:

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(types.GET_LOGIN_REQUEST, login)
  yield takeEvery(types.GET_LOGOUT_REQUEST, logout)
  yield takeLatest(types.GET_POST_REQUEST, getPosts)
  yield takeEvery(types.GET_RECENT_LIKES_REQUEST, getRecentLikes)
  yield takeEvery(types.GET_ACTIVE_GROUPS_REQUEST, getActiveGroups)
  yield takeLatest(types.GET_USER_STARS_REQUEST, getStars)
}
```

B) Implementation 2:

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    fork(watchLogin),
    fork(watchLogout),
    fork(watchGetPosts),
    fork(watchGetRecentLikes),
    fork(watchGetActiveGroups),
    fork(watchGetStars)
  ])
}
```